# How to get CSR ASN.1 Information from csr php

Tags: php, openssl, csr

I want to decode the CSR and want its Detailed Information and ASN.1 Information.

I am using following functions

```
$cert_data = openssl_csr_get_public_key($csr);
$cert_details = openssl_pkey_get_details($cert_data);
$cert_key = $cert_details['key'];
$cert_subject = openssl_csr_get_subject($csr);
```

But only getting following information:

```
Array
(
[subject] => Array
    (
        [C] => GB
        [ST] => Staffordshire
        [L] => Stoke on Trent
        [O] => Red Kestrel Consulting Ltd
        [CN] => testcert.redkestrel.co.uk
    )

[key] => -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

[details] => Array
    (
        [bits] => 2048
        [key] => -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

        [rsa] => Array
            ()

        [type] => 0
    )
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP library ['phpseclib'](https://packagist.org/packages/phpseclib/phpseclib/packages/phpseclib/) and do something like this.

```php
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

$csrInPEM = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/server.csr');
$x509 = new \phpseclib\File\X509();

$spkac = $x509->loadCSR($csrInPEM);

var_dump($spkac);
```